# How to specify the startup project path in post-build events

Tags: visual-studio-2015, console-application, nuget-package, class-library, nlua

I have a NuGet package which I add to a class library. The package adds an xcopy command to the post-build events of the class library. The xcopy copies a dll from the packages folder to the $(TargetDir) which, of course, is the bin folder of the class library.

The problem is that the dll needs to be copied to the bin folder of the start up project - in this case a console application.

Is it possible to change the $(TargetDir) to some other value so that the nuget package's dependencies are copied to the correct location at build time?